# How to use a nested While loops to display Rows and Columns in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to come up with the following output:

```
Row 1 Col A
Row 1 Col B
Row 2 Col A
Row 2 Col B
```

I am having trouble figuring out the logic to complete this task. So far I came up with the code provided below:

```
int iRowNum;
int iColLetter;

iRowNum = 1;
iColLetter = 65;

while (iColLetter < 67)
{

  System.out.println("Row " + iRowNum + " Col " + (char)iColLetter);

  iColLetter++;

  while (iRowNum < 3)
  {
    iRowNum += 1;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I receive the output of:

```
Row 1 Col A
Row 3 Col B
```

That begin said, I have a feeling I am getting close to where I need to be, but I spent a good chunk of time trying to figure out the logic behind my desired output.

**Final Question**
How do I display the rows and columns as shown in the first block of this post?

Comment: Place iColLetter++ after the inner while loop ( while (iRowNum < 3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int iRowNum = 1;
        int iColLetter = 65;
        while (iRowNum < 3) {
            iColLetter = 65;
            while (iColLetter < 67) {
                System.out.println("Row " + iRowNum + " Col " + (char) iColLetter);
                iColLetter++;
            }
            iRowNum += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Row 1 Col A
Row 1 Col B
Row 2 Col A
Row 2 Col B
```

**Explanation:**

1. Since you want the `iRowNum` to go up to `2`, you start with `while (iRowNum < 3)` or `while (iRowNum <= 2)`.
2. For each value of `iRowNum`, the inner loop has to run for two times, starting with `65` i.e. you need to reset `iColLetter` to `65` before the start of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up the ordering of incrementing. This should do the job:

```
iRowNum = 1;
iColLetter = 65;

while (iRowNum < 3) {
  for(int i = 0; i + iColLetter < 67; i++){
    System.out.println("Row " + iRowNum + " Col " + (char)(iColLetter + i));
  }
  iRowNum += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the rows first and then columns. That's why you are not getting the desired output. See the following correction in your code:

```
iRowNum = 1;
while (iRowNum < 3)
{
   iColLetter = 65;
   while (iColLetter < 67)
   {  
      System.out.println("Row " + iRowNum + " Col " + (char)iColLetter);    
      iColLetter++;
   }    
   iRowNum += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    iRowNum = 1;
    iColLetter = 65;

    while (iRowNum < 3) {
        iColLetter = 65;
        while (iColLetter < 67) {

            System.out.println("Row " + iRowNum + " Col " + (char) iColLetter);

            iColLetter++;


        }
        iRowNum += 1;
    }
```

**Output**

```
Row 1 Col A
Row 1 Col B
Row 2 Col A
Row 2 Col B
```

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted an answer as close as possible to your code. I had to make several minor changes - you should analyze each one to understand the subtle differences each line of code on how loops work, and how in some cases you need to reinitialize variables/ restructure for loops.

```
int iRowNum = 1;
int iColLetter = 65;

while (iRowNum < 3)
{    
  while (iColLetter < 67)
  {      
    System.out.println("Row " + iRowNum + " Col " + (char)iColLetter);//print alphabet for the given row
    iColLetter++;//increment the alphabet
  }
  iRowNum += 1;//row 1 printed, point to row 2
  iColLetter=65;//row 1 printed, reinitialize to start printing at A
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output has only two rows that mean the program is not getting into the inner while loop to print. The reason is iColLetter = 65 and it increased to 57 and stop going inside while loop. So you have to reset iColLetter = 65 in the outer loop.
Look at the example

```
public class NestWhileLoop {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int iRowNum = 1;
        int iColLetter = 65;


        while (iRowNum < 3) {

            while (iColLetter < 67){

                System.out.println("Row " + iRowNum + " Col " + (char)iColLetter);

                iColLetter++;
            }
            iColLetter = 65;
            iRowNum ++;

        }

   }

}
```